# Covariant derivative of contracted tensor product

Tags: differential-geometry, affine-geometry, connections

I've followed a number of derivations of the coordinate expression for the covariant derivative of a one-form: $\nabla_\delta \omega_\alpha$.  To summarize, one strategy is

> We know how to take covariant derivatives of scalar functions and vector fields.  Since the "product" of a one-form and a vector field is scalar, and we know how the covariant derivative behaves under "products", we can derive the covariant derivative for one-forms too.

So we start by examining $\nabla_u(\omega \otimes v)$:
$$\nabla_u(\omega \otimes v) = \nabla_u \omega \otimes v + \omega \nabla_u \otimes v$$
or in coordinates
$$\nabla_\delta(\omega_\alpha b^\beta) = (\nabla_\delta \omega_\alpha) v^\beta + \omega_\alpha (\nabla_\delta v^\beta)$$
$$= (\nabla_\delta \omega_\alpha) v^\beta + \omega_\alpha (\partial_\delta v^\beta) + \omega_\alpha \Gamma^\beta_{\gamma\delta}v^\gamma$$

Contracting on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ on both sides we get $$\nabla_\delta(\omega_\alpha v^\alpha) = (\nabla_\delta \omega_\alpha) v^\alpha + \omega_\alpha (\partial_\delta v^\alpha) + \omega_\alpha \Gamma^\alpha_{\gamma\delta}v^\gamma.$$

The left hand side $\omega_\alpha v^\alpha$ is a scalar function, so $$\nabla_\delta(\omega_\alpha v^\alpha) = (\partial_\delta \omega_\alpha)v^\alpha + \omega_\alpha(\partial_\delta v^\alpha)$$
so with the appropriate cancelling I can get my answer.  **Why was I allowed to treat the product $\omega_\alpha v^\alpha$ as a scalar function when I differentiated?**  I understand that the action of a one-form on a vector field is a scalar function, but I expanded this as some kind of product.  It's not a tensor product of $\omega$ and $v$, rather a contracted tensor product.  Should I think of this as just a set of $n^2$ derivatives?  What is the correct interpretation of the covariant derivative of $\omega_\alpha v^\alpha$?

Comment: One attempted explanation: $\omega_\alpha$ and $v^\beta$ are each a collection of $n$ functions.  $\omega_\alpha v^\alpha$ is shorthand for $\omega_1v^1 + \ldots + \omega_n v^n$.  This is in $\mathcal{F}(M)$ so the covariant derivative reduces to partial differentiation.  $\partial_\delta(\omega_1v^1 + \ldots + \omega_n v^n)$ is shorthand for the $n$ partial derivatives of this function.  Then, of course, the partial derivative expands as usual: $(\partial_\delta\omega_1)v^1 + \omega_1(\partial_\delta v^1) + \ldots + (\partial_\delta\omega_1)v^1 + \omega_1(\partial_\delta v^1)$

Comment: Second attempted explanation: the one-form $\omega$ expands as $(\omega_1 \epsilon^1 + \ldots + \omega_n \epsilon^n)$ with respect to basis covector fields $(\epsilon^j)$.  By the time we've collected terms in the action on $(v^1 e^1 + \ldots + v^n e_n)$ we have a scalar function answer $\omega_\beta v^\alpha \delta_\alpha^\beta = \omega_\beta v^\beta$.  By this point, we're not talking about the action of a covector on a vector as a linear functional, we're just talking about a sum of products of scalar functions.

Comment: Your explanation are correct.